ThreadPoolExecutor submit method thread creation error
I'm running a stream data processor on AWS ECS (EC2) by polling for messages in an SQS queue.
I use a ThreadPool as shown below (some of the code is omitted for brevity):
def process_messages(self, messages):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    success = 0
    timed_out = False
    thread_future = executor.submit(self._process, messages)
    try:
        succeeded = thread_future.result(timeout=self._message_processing_timeout)
        
        # omitted: handling succeeded messages

    except TimeoutError as e:
        timed_out = True
        print("Timed out!")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{repr(e)}")

    if timed_out:
        # omitted: kill process running this worker

    executor.shutdown(wait=False)
    return

I sometimes get the error error: can't start new thread from executor.submit(). After receiving this error, the worker stop processing messages and they start building up in my DLQ. I suspect that there is insufficient memory and that is preventing the thread from being created. Further, I think the lack of error handling here is causing the threadpool to be stuck in some state that prevents it from processing further messages. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.
How do I gracefully handle this error? I am considering moving the executor.submit() error into the try catch but don't know if that is the right way to deal with this.

Have you considered running a finite number of threads then pass the messages via a queue?

@SIGHUP How different would that be compared to the existing logic that uses a ThreadPool? I increased the memory in my ECS Tasks and it seemed to have fixed the issue for now. But I believe at higher loads I'll have the same problem.

I have never seen a "can't start new thread" error. I'm just guessing that by reducing the number of potential concurrent threads you may not see this error. Remember that constructing a ThreadPoolExecutor without any argument will create a pool size of min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4). That may be too many for your environment
